# React Native Undefined is not a function

Tags: android, react-native, undefined-function

I am following the React Native tutorial for iOS at: https://www.raywenderlich.com/126063/react-native-tutorial

As there is a dearth of tutorials for Android in React-Native, I am attempting to transmit the iOS link above to Android, but the error appears as:

[image]

I changed `NavigatorIOS` to `Navigator` inline:

```
'use strict';
//var React = require('react-native');

import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  Navigator,
  Image,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
var styles = React.StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: 'black',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
    margin: 80
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});


class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <React.Text style={styles.text}>Hello World (Again)</React.Text>;    
  }
}


class PropertyFinderApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'Property Finder',
          component: HelloWorld,
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

React.AppRegistry.registerComponent('PropertyFinder', function() { return PropertyFinderApp });
```

I am relatively new to React-Native, how can this be alleviated?

Comment: Do you want to replicate the example that they have in the docs.. you don't have a renderScene defined it seems...

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content

Comment: @Abhay, is there a source for Android React-Native tutorial? Similar to the one I found?

Comment: Not that i know off, but i believe the whole point of react native is that it should work for both - Ofcourse some features may be native dependent.

Answer (score 0):

NavigatorIOS is a (as the name suggests) iOs-only component, with a different API than the Navigator component. The Navigator component by the way is the officially supported one by the React Native team, so that's probably the one you should try to use anyway.

For more information, compare https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html & 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html

To come back to your working example, you need to add the renderScene prop to your Navigator component. I've also changed initialRoute so it has a key to be identified with in the renderScene method (it works cleaner than passing components in my opinion).

```
<Navigator
    style={styles.container}
    initialRoute={{
      title: 'Property Finder',
      component: 'HelloWorld',
    }}
    renderScene ={this._renderScene.bind(this)}
  />
```

then add the _renderScene method:

```
_renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if (route.component == 'HelloWorld') {
      return <HelloWorld />
    }
    // return a default homescreen or something when the route is not matched
   return <Home />
}
```